# Core Email Vs PHPMailer Component

Tags: cakephp, phpmailer

Can anyone tell me the differences between the Core Email and PHPMailer Component?
Suggest me the best...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "Core Email"?  Do you mean to say the `EmailComponent` inside CakePHP? It's a very convenient wrapper for providing out of the box e-mail functionality.