# Email component versus PHPMailer with cakePHP

Tags: php, email, cakephp

What are the core differences between the email component on cakephp and the phpmailer vendor for cakephp?

Does phpmailer *use* the email component?
Is just using the email component sufficient? What does phpmailer add to the picture?

---

This question is related to (but not exactly the same as):
[Core Email Vs PHPMailer Component](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6040085/561731)

Comment: If you're talking about PHPMailer from worxware.com, then no, it's its own complete email sending package and doesn't depend on any external libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHPMailer is a completely independent piece of software.

Can't say much about them, but as always, PHPMailer must implement features that are not supported by EmailComponent.

I've heard that it's the best option for attached files, but i did proved it.

I think you can do bulk sending to.

Hope it helps.

You could compare APIs.

http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=methods
vs.
http://api.cakephp.org/class/email-component

Comment: you can send attachments with the Email component though: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1638/Attachments

Comment: Yes, you can, but beyond the basics, sending attached files might get difficult.